# Pure virtual function vs. virtual function?

Tags: c++

I'm developing a class with some functionality that I think might need to be extended later, but not now. If the class were to be extended, then I think this would make instantiating the base class meaningless.

For example, let's say my base class is a tree. One approach would be to just put everything that the tree needs to do for my purposes in the tree class and leave it at that. However, this tree might be useful in other aspects of the program later on in life, so I've thought about creating a pure virtual `onNodeVisited` function.  Derived classes could then implement their own version of `onNodeVisited`, and not have to worry about the specifics of the tree traversal defined in the based class.

Does it make sense to not use a pure virtual function and keep the tree functionality and application-specific functionality in one class (virtual `onNodeVisited`)? Or, should I make the tree class abstract and implement one sub-class for the application-specific part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't decide that now.  Later you could make an abstract base class for Tree and move code there, if that made sense.

Another option to inheritance for this kind of thing is a pointer-to-function or functor type to call.  It's a lot easier to reuse, because you don't have to keep making new classes for each new situation.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this has to be decided on a case by case basis, and for the tree example it would seem that a crucial decision/question is whether all users of the tree would need/want to implement the onNodeVisited function.  If the tree can equally be used with the other parts of the interface (e.g. it supports `get_next_child()`-style iteration, or some "path" lookup), then it sounds like a tree could be useful to people who never intend to visit each node, and would therefore not want to implement an `onNodeVisited` function.  In that case, `onNodeVisited` should not be pure virtual, now or ever.  If your design decision is to have the tree's interface so restrictive that the class is useless without visitation, then you might insist that people implement `onNodeVisited` by making it pure virtual.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two choices that strike me as reasonably sensible.

If you're just thinking in terms of things that *might* eventually become useful, then I'd go the YAGNI route, and leave it out completely until or unless you find a real need for it.

If you're *quite* certain you're really going to need it, and just don't have enough of the other code written to put it to use *yet*, then it's worth designing into the class, even though you aren't using it yet.

This does *not* sound like a good situation for a pure virtual function though. A pure virtual function means 1) the class containing the pure virtual function *cannot* be instantiated directly -- it can only be used as a base class, and 2) to be able to create objects of a derived class, they *must* provide an implementation of the pure virtual function .

In other words, a pure virtual function would indicate almost the opposite of your situation. A pure virtual function *must* be overridden before objects of the class can exist at all. You're (at most) building in a "hook" to make a specific future expansion easy.

I'll repeat my advice above: unless you're *quite* certain this *will* be used, it's probably best to just design in what you *do* need, and leave it at that. If you *do* decide you need (or really, really want) to include it, I'd try to keep it as loosely coupled as reasonable. The obvious route to that would be to use the visitor pattern. This defines a separate visitor class that handles visiting and processing nodes. The tree node class would include an extra function (traditionally named `accept`) that takes one parameter: a pointer (or reference) to a visitor object. The visitor class is a typically-abstract base class with a member function (traditionally named `visit`) for doing processing on a node. This typically *is* an abstract base class.

Then, when you decide what processing you really want to do on each node, you derive a new class from `visitor` that overrides `visit` to do the per-node processing. The tree needs no modification at all. It's well-known pattern (even among C++ programmers, who are generally a lot less "friendly" toward patterns that others) so assuming you use the normal names, most will recognize it quite quickly and easily. It also helps that the code itself is normally pretty trivial -- the `accept` normally looks something like this:

```
struct tree_node;

class visitor { 
    virtual void visit(tree_node *node) = 0;
};

struct tree_node { 
    void accept(visitor *v) { v->visit(this); }

    // ...
};
```

Then to add processing, you derive from visitor, and override `visit` to do the processing you need. The tree side of things needs no modification at all. This also has the nicety that a single visitor class can be written to visit more than one type of node (even if the nodes are not related by inheritance).